# How can I import a link address from certain labeled e-mails into Google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have autogenerated sale confirmation emails coming in when I make a sale on my website store. I am trying to get the buyer's e-mail address that is attached to the e-mail body as a link (the address is not shown on the body unless I click on a link that says "send the buyer an email" and that redirects me to my email sender app).

I need this email address to be imported into a script that will send an automated email to this buyer with certain information about his order that is imported from a spreadsheet.

I tried using Cloud HQ which is a browser extension that collects data from the email body and sends it to a spreadsheet, but it did not succeed on finding the email address since it was not shown on the body.

I can see the email address that I need when click on show "Original Message" on the Gmail platform which displays the full codes behind the email.

Is there any way I can extract that email address and import it into a Google script?

Comment: Try using regular expressions.

Comment: Yep, use Regex. You can test it [here](https://regexr.com/). Try it and edit your post with your findings.